# Need an API in Objective-c that yield locations/districts near a point (with some suggested name)

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.3

Something like what google provide:
https://maps.google.com/maps/suggest?q=kepa&cp=13&ll=-6.186877,106.772409&spn=0.294207,0.672226

As you see I am looking for location that contains "kepa" near -6.186877,106.772409

Google API has 3 problems

1. I don't know what the city is
2. I don't know if it's json
3. Slower
4. Doesn't tell me the latitude longitude

I do not want to use that google map API. Does apple has it's own?

I've heard that since we have apple map there's API for that?

```
{suggestion:[{query:"Kepala Ganding, Batam, Riau, Indonesia",interpretation:{term:[{start:0,end:14,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x31d9eeb93f631de3:0xef236d0021b64b93",matched:1,target:1,term_start:0,term_end:4,type:2626},{start:16,end:21,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x31d9bce8c054ce05:0x3039d80b220cbb0",type:37},{start:23,end:27,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x2e27575819b13e77:0x836f02946cb5bdb1",type:545},{start:29,end:38,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x2c4c07d7496404b7:0xe37b4de71badf485",type:33}]},operation:2,target_type:2626,confidence:0.57893509238918672,confidence_level:0},{query:"Kepanjen, Jawa Timur, Indonesia",interpretation:{term:[{start:0,end:8,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x2e789e548f017007:0x4027a76e35316d0",matched:1,target:1,term_start:0,term_end:4,type:37},{start:10,end:20,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x2da393f79feeb5c5:0x1030bfbca7cb850",type:545},{start:22,end:31,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x2c4c07d7496404b7:0xe37b4de71badf485",type:33}]},operation:2,target_type:37,confidence:0.11725665758796824,confidence_level:0},{query:"Kepayang, Indonesia",interpretation:{term:[{start:0,end:8,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x2e1ba78275a0cf75:0xa45a91dd58607b35",matched:1,target:1,term_start:0,term_end:4,type:2626},{start:10,end:19,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x2c4c07d7496404b7:0xe37b4de71badf485",type:33}]},operation:2,target_type:2626,confidence:0.11208249413663574,confidence_level:0},{query:"Kepandean, Serang, Banten, Indonesia",interpretation:{term:[{start:0,end:9,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x2e41f44269c03ea5:0x501e8f1fc2968b0",matched:1,target:1,term_start:0,term_end:4,type:9939},{start:11,end:17,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x2e418b0dbb534a61:0x301e8f1fc28b8d0",type:37},{start:19,end:25,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x2e418ad6c40db999:0xbed39aab8b1ab3e9",type:545},{start:27,end:36,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x2c4c07d7496404b7:0xe37b4de71badf485",type:33}]},operation:2,target_type:9939,confidence:0.06721898275125876,confidence_level:0},{query:"Kepahiang, Bengkulu, Indonesia",interpretation:{term:[{start:0,end:9,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x2e3132d5a9fe2a25:0xd5ad9f53d01c3dfc",matched:1,target:1,term_start:0,term_end:4,type:37},{start:11,end:19,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x2e36b01e37e39279:0x511cfb65c4a3b1e1",type:545},{start:21,end:30,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x2c4c07d7496404b7:0xe37b4de71badf485",type:33}]},operation:2,target_type:37,confidence:0.019882878369774697,confidence_level:0},{query:"KEPAHIANG Furniture, Depok, Jawa Barat, Indonesia",interpretation:{term:[{start:0,end:19,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x2e69ec8425024879:0x27573ef3b43c6621",matched:1,target:1,term_start:0,term_end:4,type:3395},{start:21,end:26,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x2e69ec0828bcde9f:0x301576d150524f0",type:37},{start:28,end:38,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x2e68e6398252477f:0xbc18a454fc8e9d7e",type:545},{start:40,end:49,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x2c4c07d7496404b7:0xe37b4de71badf485",type:33}]},operation:2,target_type:3395,confidence:0.01028739546799113,confidence_level:0},{query:"Keparakan, Yogyakarta, Indonesia",interpretation:{term:[{start:0,end:9,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x2e7a579be2a92fd1:0x5027a76e356af40",matched:1,target:1,term_start:0,term_end:4,type:9939},{start:11,end:21,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x2e7a5787bd5b6bc5:0x21723fd4d3684f71",type:37},{start:23,end:32,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x2c4c07d7496404b7:0xe37b4de71badf485",type:33}]},operation:2,target_type:9939,confidence:0.010032870427200417,confidence_level:0},{query:"Kepatihan, Menganti, Jawa Timur, Indonesia",interpretation:{term:[{start:0,end:9,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x2e7800926b5108c5:0x5027a76e358f930",matched:1,target:1,term_start:0,term_end:4,type:9938},{start:11,end:19,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x2e7800d5cc71210b:0x4027a76e3532ba0",type:37},{start:21,end:31,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x2da393f79feeb5c5:0x1030bfbca7cb850",type:545},{start:33,end:42,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x2c4c07d7496404b7:0xe37b4de71badf485",type:33}]},operation:2,target_type:9938,confidence:0.0097742005878392671,confidence_level:0},{query:"Kepandean, Dukuhturi, Jawa Tengah, Indonesia",interpretation:{term:[{start:0,end:9,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x2e6fb99a2e7a4f67:0x5027a76e3565d30",matched:1,target:1,term_start:0,term_end:4,type:9938},{start:11,end:20,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x2e6fbbb51a3425b5:0x9102690e4c1fe200",type:37},{start:22,end:33,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x2e65759b9cd518dd:0xc377d19d8fedbc46",type:545},{start:35,end:44,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x2c4c07d7496404b7:0xe37b4de71badf485",type:33}]},operation:2,target_type:9938,confidence:0.0074828863815685522,confidence_level:0},{query:"Kepatihan Kulon, Surakarta, Jawa Tengah, Indonesia",interpretation:{term:[{start:0,end:15,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x2e7a168b60000447:0x5027a76e356c7b0",matched:1,target:1,term_start:0,term_end:4,type:9939},{start:17,end:26,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x2e7a16627ad11ab1:0xe7fe4e0454bc3095",type:37},{start:28,end:39,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x2e65759b9cd518dd:0xc377d19d8fedbc46",type:545},{start:41,end:50,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x2c4c07d7496404b7:0xe37b4de71badf485",type:33}]},operation:2,target_type:9939,confidence:0.0059051329667912439,confidence_level:0}],probability_sum:[0.0003222943435917154]}
```

Comment: So you want exactly the same functionality as the Google one, but specifically don't want to use it?

Comment: Apple API is faster also is that json in that google API yield?

Answer (score 1):

why not simply use google api ? 
the jsonResponse is pretty clear.

Comment: I used to use google API. I am not sure I am using the correct one. Which one anyway?